# SFSafariViewControllerDelegate methods not called when assigning delegate to something other than view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a simple view controller that presents a SFSafariViewController when a link button is tapped.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SafariDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *url;
@property(nonatomic, weak) SafariDelegate *safariDelegate;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.url = @"http://www.google.com";
}

- (IBAction)linkTapped:(id)sender {
    SFSafariViewController *vc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
    SafariDelegate *safariDelegate = [[SafariDelegate alloc] init];
    vc.delegate = safariDelegate;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

SafariDelegate conforms to SFSafariViewControllerDelegate and just logs when the delegate methods fire.

SafariDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>

@interface SafariDelegate : NSObject <SFSafariViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

---

SafariDelegate.m

```
#import "SafariDelegate.h"

@implementation SafariDelegate

- (NSArray<UIActivity *> *)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller activityItemsForURL:(NSURL *)URL     title:(nullable NSString *)title
{
    NSLog(@"safariViewController activityItemsForURL");

    return @[];
}

- (void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"safariViewControllerDidFinish");
}


- (void)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller didCompleteInitialLoad:(BOOL)didLoadSuccessfully
{
    NSLog(@"safariViewController didCompleteInitialLoad");
}

@end
```

When I tap the button, the safariviewcontroller loads the page up properly but the delegate methods are never called (including when I hit 'Done'). I stuck a break point at the line where the 'vc' is presented and confirmed that the delegate is properly set at that point. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SafariViewController` doesn't retain its delegate, so it gets deallocated immediately after your `linkTapped:` method returns since nothing else has a strong reference to it.

You need to keep a strong reference to it somewhere.  You could probably just change the property you have in your current view controller to `strong` and store it there.  You could also keep it in an associated object on the safari view controller.

Answer (score 3):

This same problem was occur for me too.
I have created "SafariViewController inside of function". So, SafariViewController memory was cleared. So, I can't able to get trigger from SafariViewControllerDelegate.

Finally I found a solution this problem.

When ever You create a **SFSafariViewController** in a class. You must declare it as a *global variable*.

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    var safariVC: SFSafariViewController!
}
```

then you can assign your *SafariViewController*.

```
func config(_ loadUrl: URL) {

   if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
       let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
       config.barCollapsingEnabled = true
       config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
       safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: loadUrl, configuration: config)
   } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
      safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: loadUrl)
   }
}
```

then set a delegate

```
self.safariVC.delegate = self
```

finally present safariViewController.

```
 UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now surely safariViewController delegate will be trigger.

```
// MARK: - SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
extension Foo: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        print("SafariVC is dismissed")
    }
}
```